# How to change the nib uiimageview image inside init method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, three20

I used the following code to change the image of uiimageview and this works for me

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instant_poetry_small.png" ];
     drawImage.image = tempImage;
}


-(id)initWithImage:(NSString *)img{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    return self;
}
```

But i want to change image of uiimageview inside init method. For this i tried the following code but it didn't change the image of uiimageview.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(id)initWithImage:(NSString *)img{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instant_poetry_small.png" ];
    drawImage.image = tempImage;
    return self;
}
```

Below is my application delegate method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];

     TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.window = _window;

    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"tt://appPhotos" toSharedViewController:[PhotoViewController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://photo/detail?name=(initWithImage:)" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tt://photo/detail?name=%@",@"level_me_up_small.png"]]];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Can you tell me what is the difference between above sample code?

Comment: Any one can tell me that how can we change the image in xib's uiimageview object at runtime. I am using initWithNibName to load my xib and want to change the image in my xib.

Comment: `- (void)loadView{
   [super loadView];
    
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(save:) ];
   
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotoView" owner:self options:nil];
    for(id oneObject in nib){
        self.view = (UIView *)oneObject;
       
    }
     UIImage *camImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName] retain];
    drawImage.image = camImage;
    [camImage release];
}
`

Comment: `-(id)initWithImage:(NSString *)img{
      self.imageName = img;
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",self.imageName];
      return self;
}`

Comment: I solved my problem by using above two methods.

Answer (score 2):

In the method `viewDidLoad` the nib is done loading and all UI elements are available.
Don't  call `viewDidLoad` from `init` since there is now way to tell if the view (read nib) is loaded.

The `initWithImage` methode your wrote isn't correct and does not work in that way.
If you do want to create a custom `init`, it more like this"

```
-(id)initWithImage:(NSString *)img{
   self= [super init];

   if (self) {
      // Create a property for this call where you keep the image.
      self.drawImage = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
   }

   return self;
}
```

But this does not load any NIB, so you have to either call super initWithNIB: or create the elements via code.

Comment: according to my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in app delegate i redirected to initWithImage method in my PhotoView class. if i commented the [super viewDidLoad] in my init then still i am not able to change the image in uiimageview. Ok can you tell me that which method will be called first when i redirected to PhotoView class inside my app delegate??

Comment: No I can not, you use Three20 which I've never used. But I suggest you start learn about how `UIViewController` are build. Call a init method is the first thing that gets called,only after that does the `NIB` get load.

Comment: I found something that when i redirected to my photo view class then iniWithImage is the method that called first and after that viewDidLoad is called.